# Check null and split value in textbox in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am facing very simple issue but not getting solution over it.
I have textbox in my ssrs report, I am passing value "1;prashant" or null to it. Now, if I pass  value "1;prashant" to textbox then textbox should show only "prashant" and If I am passing nothing then it should be blank.

```
I have tried following IIF condition:
=IIF(IsNothing(FieldS!WIAPPORVER.Value),"",Split(Fields!WIAPPORVER.Value,"#")(1).ToString())
```

But, I above code is giving an error ["#error" shows in textbox] if I am passing blank value.

Please let me know, where I am wrong in this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are relying on the `IIf` expression short circuiting, but SSRS `IIf` expressions do not short circuit - the expression will try and work out `Split(Fields!WIAPPORVER.Value,"#")(1).ToString()` for all rows and fail when this value doesn't exist.

You can get this going by using text expressions, which don't get this error.

With test data:

[image]

And a simple table:

[image]

I have added columns with both your existing expression and a new expression:

```
=Right(Fields!WIAPPORVER.Value, Len(Fields!WIAPPORVER.Value) - InStr(Fields!WIAPPORVER.Value, "#"))
```

This new expression works for NULL values, empty strings and strings with no delimiter present:

[image]

Comment: This solution relies on completely forgoing the SSRS problem with another completely different tool, which is SQL. Not possible 90% of the time and rather cumbersome to relie on another tool when SSRS fails to do proper short-circuiting.

Comment: Hi, @user3285866. I don't understand your comment, sorry. The suggested solution is an SSRS expression, not SQL; the SQL is included only to show how a sample dataset was generated.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways of doing this, but this is what my head came up with at the time:

```
=IIF(
    IsNothing(Fields!WIAPPROVER.Value)
    ,""
    ,Right(Fields!WIAPPROVER.Value,Len(Fields!WIAPPROVER.Value) -InStr(Fields!WIAPPROVER.Value,";"))
)
```

I believe SSRS is trying to compute everything in the report at runtime, so in your case it is still trying to fetch index 1 from an array even though there is nothing in it and it crashes.

Edit: Changed parameters to Fields. I created a parameter to remake the issue at my side.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the split out of the `iif`. Then in your `iif`, if field is nothing create a string that when split will return ""

```
=Split(IIF(IsNothing(FieldS!WIAPPORVER.Value),"#", Fields!WIAPPORVER.Value),"#")(1)
```